# Black screen and realignment when switching to hyper-v window

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

When in situation

- currently on a host machine
- running and connected to a local hyper-v machine
- window with Hyper-V VM is minimalized
- Hyper-V session is set to fullscreen
- host and the VM are both Windows 10 with latest updates

then whenever the Hyper-v Virtual Machine Connection window is restored to full screen, the screen goes black for a second, then sometimes the windows within the VM are misaligned (e.g. not accounting for a vertical start bar), they stay that way for a moment and then start realigning themselves until the VM is finally usable.

There is some flicker even if the session is set to be windowed, though significantly less.

I am used to switching from host to VM often and also prefer full screen when in VM and this is very annoying.

Switching host Windows to Performance mode, disabling animations etc. didn't help.

On Windows 8.1 switching was very smooth, this has started after upgrade to 10 (currently on 1803 but the issue was before as well).
Is this something known? Any suggestions what to try to fix this?
Thank you