# Issue with switching back to Hyper-V window

Tags: windows-11, hyper-v

On Windows 11 I use Hyper-V in fullscreen 2 monitors. Whenever I minimize the hyper-v window to go back to host machine and then again go back to hyper-v, the screen goes black for several seconds and then some (but not all) windows are moved to the other monitor than the one where they were originally.

It's gen 1 configuration 11 with guest services. Windows is updated

Does this have any fix?

Comment: Two workarounds to this bug are suggested in [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/652191/hyper-v-full-screen-on-dual-monitor-does-not-resto). Let me know if one of them helps with the problem.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately not. I tried unchecking and re-checking Enhanced session and that didn't help. Then I checked host scaling which is 100%, the Hyper-V scaling was not filled in, so I set it to custom = 100% and had to sign in again. But after that enhanced session was disabled, so I enabled it again. And it didn't help either, unfortunately (edit: grammar)

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT figured it out eventually - connecting via RDP works perfectly for me, need to forgo connecting directly via Hyper-V

Comment: With this being a follow-up to https://superuser.com/questions/1355451/black-screen-and-realignment-when-switching-to-hyper-v-window I've been trying to solve this for 5+ years. Thank you, AI friend